# jquery lightbox techique

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Lightbox used some kind of javascript/jquery to check when an user clicks outside of an image and than lightbox closed.

Can someone name that Javascript/jQuery function for me.

**I Don't ask for code! , Just for the name !**

Thx in advance

Comment: it's name is `click` http://api.jquery.com/click if the overlay gets clicked, the overlay and lightbox gets closed.

Comment: What's so wrong about this question?

Comment: It can't be too bad if it isn't already closed, but basically it isn't very clear what you are asking. Do you want to know what event is being used? What the techinque is called? For example, i answered with "click", but others are suggesting ways to do an overlay with popup.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, next time It will be better :)

Answer (score 2):

What a lot of the modal libraries do is create an overlay of the full window size, either transparent or invisible, and detect a click on that element. This is in addition to the "content window" element. It's just detecting a click and then calling your close routine.

Comment: Thank you! , I go search for an code example for this technique

Answer (score 1):

There are many. Here is a site that lists ten - I expect most, if not all of them to display the specific requirement you have.

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts